# Display HTML image with file selected using FileDialog

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I spent around four hour searching method to display the image file chosen by FileDialog in browser in  tag. Some pages are suggesting that the src attribute of  tag be updated with the content of the file. But this does not seem right. The src attribute takes file path and not the content of the file (using filerreader.readAsDataURL(file)).
The compiler complains :

```
Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

on the code :

```
document.getElementById('img-userPhoto')?.setAttribute('src', this.result);
```

So, the next alternative, if I set the src attribute with URL that points to file on client machine, it is not allowed for security reasons. So the alternative left is render the file using content only.

So, can anybody suggest how to render  with content of file object?
The should be some API in JavaScript, that take the HTML image element and render the content of file object that contains Image File.

Thanks,
Nealesh

Answer (score 0):

The following code finally solved my issue.

```
onSelectFile3(event : any ) { // called each time file input changes
  
  
      if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
    
        
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
    
        reader.onload = (event2) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
          if(event2.target == null) return;
          if(event2.target.result == null) return;
          document.getElementById('img-userPhoto')?.setAttribute('src', event2.target.result as string);

        }
      }
    }
```

The UI is:

```
         <tr> 
            <td> Photo </td> 
            <td><input type="file" 
                       accept="image/*" 
                       class="file-input"       
                       (change)="onSelectFile3($event)" #fileUpload>
            </td>
         </tr>
          
          <tr>  
            <td> 
              <img id="img-userPhoto"  
                   [src]="imageSource" 
                   width="200" height="200" /> 
            </td> 
         </tr>
```